# Sum grouped observations based on time window of given days

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, lag

Here an example of my data.frame:

```
    df = read.table(text = 'ID  Day Episode Count
28047   6000    143 7
28049   6000    143 7
29002   6000    143 7
29003   6000    143 7
30003   6000    143 7
30004   6000    143 7
32010   6000    143 7
30001   7436    47  6
33021   7436    47  6
33024   7436    47  6
33034   7436    47  6
37018   7436    47  6
40004   7436    47  6
29003   7300    111 6
30003   7300    111 6
30004   7300    111 6
32010   7300    111 6
30001   7300    111 6
33021   7300    111 6
2001    7438    54  5
19007   7438    54  5
20002   7438    54  5
22006   7438    54  5
22007   7438    54  5
32010   7301    99  5
30001   7301    99  5
33021   7301    99  5
2001    7301    99  5
19007   7301    99  5
27021   5998    158 5
28015   5998    158 5
28047   5998    158 5
28049   5998    158 5
29001   5998    158 5
21009   7437    65  4
24001   7437    65  4
25005   7437    65  4
25009   7437    65  4
14001   7435    81  4
16004   7435    81  4
17001   7435    81  4
17005   7435    81  4
21009   7299    77  4
24001   7299    77  4
25005   7299    77  4
25009   7299    77  4
29002   5996    158 4
29003   5996    158 4
27002   5996    158 4
27003   5996    158 4
33014   5999    56  3
33023   5999    56  3
25005   5999    56  3
27021   5995    246 2
33006   5995    246 2
8876    7439    765 2
5421    7439    765 2
6678    7298    68  1
34001   5994    125 1
4432    7440    841 1', header = TRUE)
```

What I need to do is for each unique `Day` observation look for its `Count` value and add it to the previous 3 days' `Count` ones (i.e. 4-days time window).

e.g. 1) `Day` = 6000, sum 7 (`Count` value) to `Count` values of `Day` 5999, 5998 and 5997 (the last one not present in the `df`), which are respectively 3, 5 and 0 -> 7 + 3 + 5 + 0 = `new_Count` 15;

2) next `Day` = 7436, sum 6 to `Count` values of 7435, 7434 and 7433 -> 6 + 4 + 0 + 0 = `new_Count` 10;

and so on up to the last `Day` within `df`.

Desired output:

```
ID    Day  new_Episode new_Count
2001    7438    1   19
19007   7438    1   19
20002   7438    1   19
22006   7438    1   19
22007   7438    1   19
21009   7437    1   19
24001   7437    1   19
25005   7437    1   19
25009   7437    1   19
30001   7436    1   19
33021   7436    1   19
33024   7436    1   19
33034   7436    1   19
37018   7436    1   19
40004   7436    1   19
14001   7435    1   19
16004   7435    1   19
17001   7435    1   19
17005   7435    1   19
8876    7439    2   17
5421    7439    2   17
2001    7438    2   17
19007   7438    2   17
20002   7438    2   17
22006   7438    2   17
22007   7438    2   17
21009   7437    2   17
24001   7437    2   17
25005   7437    2   17
25009   7437    2   17
30001   7436    2   17
33021   7436    2   17
33024   7436    2   17
33034   7436    2   17
37018   7436    2   17
40004   7436    2   17
32010   7301    3   16
30001   7301    3   16
33021   7301    3   16
2001    7301    3   16
19007   7301    3   16
29003   7300    3   16
30003   7300    3   16
30004   7300    3   16
32010   7300    3   16
30001   7300    3   16
33021   7300    3   16
21009   7299    3   16
24001   7299    3   16
25005   7299    3   16
25009   7299    3   16
6678    7298    3   16
28047   6000    4   15
28049   6000    4   15
29002   6000    4   15
29003   6000    4   15
30003   6000    4   15
30004   6000    4   15
32010   6000    4   15
33014   5999    4   15
33023   5999    4   15
25005   5999    4   15
27021   5998    4   15
28015   5998    4   15
28047   5998    4   15
28049   5998    4   15
29001   5998    4   15
21009   7437    5   14
24001   7437    5   14
25005   7437    5   14
25009   7437    5   14
30001   7436    5   14
33021   7436    5   14
33024   7436    5   14
33034   7436    5   14
37018   7436    5   14
40004   7436    5   14
14001   7435    5   14
16004   7435    5   14
17001   7435    5   14
17005   7435    5   14
4432    7440    6   12
8876    7439    6   12
5421    7439    6   12
2001    7438    6   12
19007   7438    6   12
20002   7438    6   12
22006   7438    6   12
22007   7438    6   12
21009   7437    6   12
24001   7437    6   12
25005   7437    6   12
25009   7437    6   12
33014   5999    7   12
33023   5999    7   12
25005   5999    7   12
27021   5998    7   12
28015   5998    7   12
28047   5998    7   12
28049   5998    7   12
29001   5998    7   12
29002   5996    7   12
29003   5996    7   12
27002   5996    7   12
27003   5996    7   12
29003   7300    8   11
30003   7300    8   11
30004   7300    8   11
32010   7300    8   11
30001   7300    8   11
33021   7300    8   11
21009   7299    8   11
24001   7299    8   11
25005   7299    8   11
25009   7299    8   11
6678    7298    8   11
27021   5998    9   11
28015   5998    9   11
28047   5998    9   11
28049   5998    9   11
29001   5998    9   11
29002   5996    9   11
29003   5996    9   11
27002   5996    9   11
27003   5996    9   11
27021   5995    9   11
33006   5995    9   11
30001   7436    10  10
33021   7436    10  10
33024   7436    10  10
33034   7436    10  10
37018   7436    10  10
40004   7436    10  10
14001   7435    10  10
16004   7435    10  10
17001   7435    10  10
17005   7435    10  10
29002   5996    11  7
29003   5996    11  7
27002   5996    11  7
27003   5996    11  7
27021   5995    11  7
33006   5995    11  7
34001   5994    11  7
21009   7299    12  5
24001   7299    12  5
25005   7299    12  5
25009   7299    12  5
6678    7298    12  5
14001   7435    13  4
16004   7435    13  4
17001   7435    13  4
17005   7435    13  4
27021   5995    14  3
33006   5995    14  3
34001   5994    14  3
6678    7298    15  1
34001   5994    16  1
```

Note that the `output_df` is larger than `df` (but it's ok) and it is ranked by `-new_Count` and `-Day` with `new_Episode` column accordingly to `-new_Count` ranking.

Any suggestion?

Comment: why is the `output_df` larger?

Comment: because per each new_Count (or new_Episode) I need to show all the previous days. See my output. thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure why `output_df` has more rows than the original `data.frame`, but we can use the `by` function along with `subset` to calculate `new_Count`. Note that I've called your `data.frame` `df1` instead of `df`.

```
output_df1 <- do.call('rbind', by(df1, list(df1$Day, df1$ID), FUN = function(d){
  #grab subset of df
  sub_df <- subset(df1, Day < d$Day & Day > (d$Day - 4))
  #select unique day, count
  sub_df_u <- unique(sub_df[,-1])
  d$new_Count <- sum(sub_df_u$Count) + d$Count
  d
}))

 head(output_df1)
      ID  Day Episode Count new_Count
14  2001 7438      54     5        15
28 14001 7435      81     4         4
29 16004 7435      81     4         4
30 17001 7435      81     4         4
31 17005 7435      81     4         4
15 19007 7438      54     5        15
```

To get the `new_Episode` column, we can use the `dense_rank` function from the **`dplyr`** package:

```
output_df1$new_Episode <- dplyr::dense_rank(-output_df1$new_Count)
```

Comment: hi, thanks. I need duplicate rows per each new_Count showing all the previous days. How can I add them? thanks

Comment: p.s. in order to have my output you need to set (d$Day - 4)

Comment: p.p.s. output_df1$new_Episode <- dplyr::dense_rank(-output_df1$new_Count) is not correct as I can have duplicated new_Count observations within different episodes.

Comment: @aaaaa I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "I need duplicate rows per each new_Count showing all the previous days"

Comment: I think my desired output in the question is more than clear. thanks anyway